# Python - Pandas: Normalizing a column within a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

hope the question is not trivial.
I've been looking for answer in other threads with no luck.

I've been trying to analyze a dataset separated with a groupby, in which I added a column with a cumulative sum (cumsum) on the variable "profits".

Now, to compare results in different categories, I'd like to "normalize" the cumulative profit values dividing them with the max value they have in their group.

I've been trying using both math and lambda functions but I cannot find a Way to show the desired result.

Here part of my code with the outputs

```
us_discount = us.groupby(['Sub-Category', 'Discount'], as_index = False)['Profit'].sum()
us_discount['Cumulative Profit'] = us_discount.groupby('Sub-Category', as_index = False)['Profit'].cumsum()

print(us_discount.groupby('Sub-Category')['Cumulative Profit'].max())

us_discount['test'] = us_discount['Cumulative Profit'] / us_discount.groupby('Sub-Category')['Cumulative Profit'].max()

us_discount.head()
```

and here the results:
[image: On top the print output and below the head of my dataset]

as you can see the max are actually calculated correctly, but I cannot add them as the variable "test". I would like the print output to be the "test" column voices.

As I'm currently learning pandas, I'd like to find (if possible) a solution using the library, if possible without using lambda functions.
I know I could solve the issues using matrices or fits.

Comment: Use `.transform("max")` instead of `.max()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to do what you've asked:

```python
us_discount['Cumulative Profit'] = us_discount.groupby('Sub-Category', as_index = False)['Profit'].cumsum()
us_max = us_discount.groupby('Sub-Category')['Cumulative Profit'].max()
us_discount['test'] = us_discount['Cumulative Profit'].div(us_discount['Sub-Category'].map(us_max))
```

Sample input for `us_discount`:

```
  Sub-Category  Discount      Profit
0  Accessories       0.0  35289.2539
1  Accessories       0.2   6647.3818
2  Applicances       0.0  23183.7361
3  Applicances       0.1   1086.0808
4  Applicances       0.2   2497.8297
```

Output:

```
  Sub-Category  Discount      Profit  Cumulative Profit      test
0  Accessories       0.0  35289.2539         35289.2539  0.841490
1  Accessories       0.2   6647.3818         41936.6357  1.000000
2  Applicances       0.0  23183.7361         23183.7361  0.866110
3  Applicances       0.1   1086.0808         24269.8169  0.906685
4  Applicances       0.2   2497.8297         26767.6466  1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the result I needed.

Comment: Do you need any additional help?

Comment: Not at the moment, thanks.
I also used your helpfull response to look for different ways to do the same. 

The main problem for me was misunderstading the use of the group by.

Comment: Good to hear it was helpful. Please consider marking this answer as "accepted".